# How to fix display errors in VirtualBox and "open file" kdialog (and some other apps) when using nvidia dual monitors

Tags: nvidia, virtualbox, multiple-monitors, kde, xorg.conf

It's hard to describe but when I start some applications- VirtualBox is a latest example- it  draws some elements in offset to application window and duplicated which makes the application unusable. Only working solution I found is to just turn off the second monitor(using metamodes and xrandr) when using those apps. Is there any proper solution? I'm attaching two screenshots - one correct when I have only one monitor running and the other with the second monitor on. [image: second monitor on]  [image: second monitor off]

It also happens in KDialog Open file windows

[image: also happens in KDialog Open file windows]
Screen section of my xorg.conf:

```
Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen0"
Device         "Device0"
Monitor        "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth    24
Option         "Stereo" "0"
Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-6"
Option         "metamodes" "DFP-6: 1920x1080_144 +0+420 {AllowGSYNCCompatible=On}, DFP-0: 1920x1080_60 +1920+0 {rotation=left}; DFP-6: 1920x1080_144 +0+0 {AllowGSYNCCompatible=On}, DFP-0: NULL"
Option         "SLI" "Off"
Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: it seems like you should be asking this question at virtualbox's forum here (https://forums.virtualbox.org/)

Comment: @wraith3690001 I would if it happens only in virtualbox, but  I encountered in in many other ones (more rarely recently - that's why I cant find another example from top of my head) I assume is dependent on framework used or something similar

Comment: ok then we will need some info what os are you using is this a laptop or desktop what graphics are you using nvidia, amd, intel what driver version are you using

Comment: kubuntu 20.04 
nvidia 450.80.02(was the same on every previous version in last 5-6 years)

Comment: @wraith3690001 added one more example -still usable but impaired open file dialog

Comment: Take into account xorg.conf - one of the monitors is in portrait - it's not happening when both of them are in landscape with same resolution -the first screen offset from top is what is causing the bug to appear(or at least it seems that way)

Comment: Also appears I dolphin buy only after I use video player/preview on the right sidebar